# Indian travelling to Doha to Banglore via Kuwait,do i need transit visa to go out of airport

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, kuwait

I am travelling doha to banglore in kuwait airways, there is a short layover of 6 hours. Can I go outside of airport for sometime for my personal work?
can I know what is the process?

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: @gouse shaik What do you mean by ‘personal work’?